# How to optimise a SQL query with many of the same selections?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I've created this query, but I think it can be optimised a lot... but I don't know how?

It's a query that selected the notCompleted tasks that a student has, also it select the planned task count, and the count of how much tasks there are that he requested help for.

Later on I don't want a count but the full row of the answer that he/she requested help for, but for now I started by doing it with a count since that seemed easier.

Is there someone that can explain me how to optimise this, or where I can learn this?

```
SELECT
    gu.user_id,
    notComplete.count AS notComplete,
    planned.count AS planned,
    helpNeeded.need AS helpNeeded
FROM
    `groups_users` gu
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        a.created_by AS user_id,
        COUNT(1) AS 'count'
    FROM
        `answers` a
    WHERE
        a.deleted_at IS NULL AND a.completed_at IS NULL AND a.checked_at IS NULL
    GROUP BY
        a.created_by
) AS notComplete
ON
    notComplete.user_id = gu.user_id
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        a.created_by AS user_id,
        COUNT(1) AS 'count'
    FROM
        `answers` a
    WHERE
        a.deleted_at IS NULL
    GROUP BY
        a.created_by
) AS planned
ON
    planned.user_id = gu.user_id
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        a.created_by AS user_id,
        COUNT(1) AS need
    FROM
        `answers` a
    WHERE
        a.deleted_at IS NULL AND a.requested_help_at IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        a.created_by
) AS helpNeeded
ON
    helpNeeded.user_id = gu.user_id
INNER JOIN `users` u ON
    u.id = gu.user_id AND u.type = 'student'
WHERE
    gu.group_id = 213
```

Comment: Search for conditional aggregation. And you could improve your question by adding sample data and expected output as text or sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
SELECT
  gu.user_id,
  SUM(IF(a.deleted_at IS NULL AND a.completed_at IS NULL AND a.checked_at IS NULL,1,0)) AS notComplete,
  SUM(IF(a.deleted_at IS NULL,1,0)) AS planned,
  SUM(IF(a.deleted_at IS NULL AND a.requested_help_at IS NOT NULL,1,0)) AS helpNeeded
FROM `groups_users` gu
JOIN `users` u ON u.id = gu.user_id
LEFT JOIN `answers` a ON a.created_by = gu.user_id
WHERE gu.group_id = 213
  AND u.type = 'student'
GROUP BY gu.user_id
```

Try the following for your second question

```
SELECT
  gu.user_id,
  IF(a.deleted_at IS NULL AND a.completed_at IS NULL AND a.checked_at IS NULL,1,0) AS notComplete,
  IF(a.deleted_at IS NULL,1,0) AS planned,
  IF(a.deleted_at IS NULL AND a.requested_help_at IS NOT NULL,1,0) AS helpNeeded,
  a.* -- full answer row
FROM `groups_users` gu
JOIN `users` u ON u.id = gu.user_id
LEFT JOIN `answers` a ON a.created_by = gu.user_id
LEFT JOIN `answer_plannedday` ap ON ap.answer_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN `plannedday` p ON p.id = ap.planned_day_id
WHERE gu.group_id = 213
  AND u.type = 'student'  
  AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(p.year, '-', p.month, '-', p.day), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2016-12-01', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-04-13', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

If you want to get detail information only for notComplete you can put all the necessary conditions into WHERE

```
SELECT
  gu.user_id,
  a.* -- full answer row
FROM `groups_users` gu
JOIN `users` u ON u.id = gu.user_id
LEFT JOIN `answers` a ON a.created_by = gu.user_id
LEFT JOIN `answer_plannedday` ap ON ap.answer_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN `plannedday` p ON p.id = ap.planned_day_id
WHERE gu.group_id = 213
  AND u.type = 'student'  
  AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(p.year, '-', p.month, '-', p.day), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2016-12-01', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-04-13', '%Y-%m-%d')
  -- you say here that you want to get only these rows
  AND a.deleted_at IS NULL AND a.completed_at IS NULL AND a.checked_at IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Then one other thing, what if I want filter between dates?

The database layout is crap so I've to do this to get the dat when the task is plannen:

https://hastebin.com/jizecoqevu.sql

The thing is that I need the full rows for requested_help_at,
so there must be some kind of join right?

(then I've still two other queries to combine with this one).

Comment: I've updated my answer. Is it what you want? And I've replaced parameters into `STR_TO_DATE('2016-12-01', '%Y-%m-%d')`.

Comment: Thanks @leran2002, but as I said I need the full result (row) from the answers that have requested help between those dates, so I think I'll need a join am I right?

Comment: Sorry. I think I'm misunderstood you. I've updated the second query. If you want to get full information about answers you don't need to use GROUP BY and SUM.

Comment: And I think you can use ewerywhere JOIN instead LEFT JOIN. Try to test it, too.

Comment: I've added one more query. It's return only detail rows for notComplete. Hope it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I need! :)